# React - How to do network requests inside a setState, is my code okay?

Tags: reactjs, browser

I have a scenario where depending on a condition, I need to either update the state based on the previous state, or update the state from data received from a server. How best to do this safely?

```
this.setState((prevState: State) => {

      if (prevState.condition1) {
        return { message: "welcome"  };
      }

      if (prevState.condition2) {
        fetch(`http://someurl`)
          .then(data => data.json())
          .then(jsonData => {
             this.setState({ message: jsonData.message });
          });
      }
      return null;
    });
```

This is what I have at the moment. I am worried that some other kind of state updates could occur before the promise finishes executing because it is not being "awaited". I cannot use await within setState so this is not an option. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing the above why don't you do it like this.

```
  if (condition1) {
    this.setState((prevState: State) => ({ message: "welcome }))
  }

  if (condition2) {
    fetch(`http://someurl`)
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(jsonData => {
         this.setState({ message: jsonData.message });
      });
  }
```

- Wrap it in a function
- You can make the function async/await

Like below

```
const myFunction = async () => {
   if (condition1) {
      // ..condition1 code here ..
   }
   if (condition2) {
     try {
       const data = await fetch(`http://someurl`);
       const dataJSON = await data.json();
       this.setState({ message: dataJSON.message });
     } catch (error) {
       console.log(error);
     }
   }
}
```

- Benefits: This makes the code more readable and easier to debug in the future as well. Less nested :)

Comment: Sorry but I forgot to mention that condition1 and condition2 both depend on prevState! I have edited the code to show this. Does this not change your answer?

Comment: Adeel's solution will still work. Unless you have changed your state via "this.setState", your current state is what you need to check your conditions. To sum up, this.state is equivalent to prevState here.

Comment: @AshishAgrahari But I change the state using "this.setState" in other areas of the application. Does this not matter?

Comment: Hi @Itachinome Using the setState with the callback function only guarantees that it will be executed after all the previous setState calls are done. But if you have simultaneous state updates in your application, a new setState may be triggered while you did the api call in your previous setState call. So again after the api call finishes you need to check the state.. this may go in a vicious loop.
So the best possible solution would be to check the condition with the current state and only call the setState once you have api response.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to setState inside setState callback you just need to return state updated value. i.e

```
this.setState((prevState: State) => {

      if (condition1) {
        return { message: "welcome"  };
      }

      if (condition2) {
        fetch(`http://someurl`)
          .then(data => data.json())
          .then(jsonData => {
             return { message: jsonData.message };
          });
      }
      return null;
    });
```

Although its not recommended way . Try to avoid call inside setState as it makes code hard to read.